# How do I count the number of members in my group under the new groups settings

Tags: google-groups

I used to be able to see how many members were in our google groups account under the old system.  I cannot under the new format.  Does anyone have any ideas - google searches for an answer have drawn a blank.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to Groups Setting > Members > All Members.

See images attached:

[image: Group Settings]
[image: All Members]